# How do I keep a footer div at the bottom right?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a lot of examples regarding images that didn't work exactly for what I need.  I have a simple footer that I use for copyright/social media linking information and I would like it to float to the right so that on screen resize it doesn't interfere with the navigation that is at the upper left.

```
/* footer */

footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:20px;
   bottom:20px;
   z-index:1;
   }
footer small {
   float:right;
   clear:both;
   margin:0 0 5px 0;
```

In the html:

```
<footer>
        <small>&copy; 2003-<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                var today = new Date()
                var year = today.getFullYear()
                document.write(year)
                </script> Name of Site | <a href="Link to Site">The Site</a>
                          | <a href="Link to Site #2">Site #2</a>
        </small>
</footer>
```

Its a pretty minimal design and I'm trying to keep it really simple so when its time for me to try to optimize for mobile it will work.   Any help is appreciated.

Comment: THis is a duplicate post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `right:0` (or some number) to pull it to the right.

```
footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:20px;
    bottom:20px;
    z-index:1;
    right:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XkzjP/)**

Comment: how simple... my daily dose of, "duh"

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a width on the footer

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/b46Dw/)

```
footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:20px;
   bottom:20px;
   z-index:1;
   width:100%; /*Added*/
   }
footer small {
   float:right;
   clear:both;
   margin:0 30px 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: why do i need width:100%  it doesn't seem to change anything.  is it a browser conditional?

Comment: By default, it seems that the `footer` 's width is determined by its content. You need to explicitly state it if you want it to span the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to assign a height and width to your footer. Also make sure you give it a display type of block. Not all browsers respect footer as a block element.

Maybe something like this:

```
footer {
     position: fixed;
     display: block;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 20px;
     width: 100px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code a little bit to do the job.

```
footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom:20px;
   z-index:1;
   text-align: right;
}
footer small {
   margin:0 20px 5px 0;
}
```